# In order to show or refute: Given a real function $f$ and $a, b \in R$ then $a\leq b \Rightarrow f(a)\leq f(b)$, what should I regard?

Tags: functions, inequality, monotone-functions

Is it enough to show that $f$ is increasing or decreasing in any interval $I$ that contains both numbers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $a,b\in\mathbb R: \,a\leq b\Rightarrow f(a)\leq f(b)$ is exactly the definition of a monotonically increasing function

Comment: The if it says $f(a)\leq f(b)$ and I show that f is decreasing then the sentence is wrong right? Thanks for answering!

Comment: if you show that there are some $a,b\in\mathbb R$  for which $f(a)>f(b)$ then the sentence is wrong, i.e the function is not monotonically increasing.